# 'Named parameters' using arrays

Tags: php, arrays, oop, methods

I have some Utilities classes in my project and was considering using arrays in order to create "named parameters".

My code allows me to either chain methods or use them separately. For example I have a string class which deals with strings (a bit obvious :))

Now a sample set of methods with chaining looks like this:

```
print Utils\String::Set('my string')->UcFirst()->UcLast()->Get()
```

While the same thing without chaining looks like this:

```
$string = Utils\String::UcFirst('my string');
print Utils\String::UcLast($string);
```

This works for some methods however there is a problem with methods such as "Suffix" which has the following parameters: $string, $suffix.

This causes a problem for chaining as I would end up doing

```
Suffix(null, ' New')
```

Which is not really looking great.

Would using arrays be ok in order to provide named parameters in this case?
Then I would be able to do this for chaining:

```
Suffix(['suffix' => ' New'])
```

However I am not sure how much harder would this make maintaining the project and whether it's worth dropping the non-chaining method so that the arrays are not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not go this route. The problem with arrays as a replacement for named params is that you cannot define parameters as required or optional and cannot type hint them, which makes errors harder to find or adds the requirement of additional validation.

Think about how it is to write code using this library, if you don't know it by heart. Any IDE can quickly show the parameters a method takes, but if it only shows **array**, I have to look closer into the documentation.

I would even go further and split the static methods from the object chaining methods. Right now it seems that `String::Suffix` can be called statically with a value parameter and non-statically without a value parameter. Aside from violating E_STRICT standards, this mashes two completely different interfaces into one method.

#### This is how I would implement your API:

```
namespace Util;

class String // you might want to change the name to "Strings", "string" is a reserved keyword in PHP 7
{
    public static function Suffix($string, $suffix)
    {
        return (new StringWrapper($string))->Suffix($suffix);
    }
}
class StringWrapper
{
    private $value;
    public function __construct($string)
    {
        $this->value = $string;
    }
    public function Suffix($suffix)
    {
        return new static($this->value . $suffix);
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->value; 
    }
}
```

You'll see that the static interface in `String` is just a thin wrapper around the actual implementation in the `StringWrapper` class. `StringWrapper` is an immutable value object type and offers the methods for string manipulations. Each method call returns a new instance of the class that holds the modified value. With `__toString` you can finally convert it to a scalar string value (this is what you did with the `Get()` method)

**Voilà, no need for named parameters anymore**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This solutions looks much better and I must agree that having 2 interfaces in one method is a bad idea. You have used a static class in StringWrapper::Suffix, what does that mean? I could not find it in the PHP manual.

Comment: `new static` uses [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php). If you don't intend to allow subclasses of `StringWrapper` you could also write `new self` or `new StringWrapper`

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you're doing is transforming from prefix to an infix notation for function application. That is, instead of `f(x1,x2,…,xn)` you are writing `x1->f(x2,…,xn)`.

You can always just use prefix notation to write `S::UcLast(S::UcFirst("my string"))`. The brevity is gained from `use Utils\String as S`.

To use `->` as part of an infix notation you need a class definition like the one below (and I assume your implementation looks like this as well).

```
class UtilStringProxy
{
  public $string;

  public function __construct($string)
  {
    $this->string = $string;
  }

  public function UcFirst()
  {
    $this->string = S::UcFirst($this->string);
    return $this;
  }

  public function UcLast()
  {
    $this->string = S::UcLast($this->string);
    return $this;
  }

  public function Suffix($suffix)
  {
    $this->string = S::Suffix($this->string, $suffix);
    return $this;
  }

}
```

The first argument is peeled off. This is how we get the `f` into an infix position (between operands 1 and 2). Then you can write:

```
(new UtilStringProxy("my string"))->UcFirst()->UcLast()->Suffix("New")->string
```

Personally I do not see the desire of this over:

```
S::Suffix(S::UcLast(S::UcFirst("my string")), "New")
```

### Addendum

Function composition is another way to view this. Function application gives a left-to-right reading, whereas function composition can give you either a left-to-right or right-to-left reading just by flipping the arguments.

The example with `UtilStringProxy` is basically left-to-right function composition defined for the particular set of functions `UcFirst, UcLast, Suffix`. You can generalise from this.

```
class Compose
{
  public $f;

  public function __construct(callable $f)
  {
    $this->f = $f;
  }

  public function lr(callable $g)
  {
    $f = $this->f;
    return new Compose(function ($x) use ($f, $g) {
      return $g($f($x));
    });
  }

  public function rl(callable $g)
  {
    $f = $this->f;
    return new Compose(function ($x) use ($f, $g) {
      return $f($g($x));
    });
  }

  public function call($x)
  {
    $f = $this->f;
    return $f($x);
  }

}
```

I added the `call` method because PHP has an unfortunate weakness in its parser such that you cannot write `expr(x)` to apply `expr` to `x` for any expression — only some. If you just want the composed function back, use `->f`, and if you want to apply it right away use `->call(x)`.

Using this you can write left-to-right composition:

```
(new Compose('strtolower'))->lr('ucfirst')->call("hEllo World")
```

Or right-to-left composition:

```
(new Compose('ucfirst'))->rl('strtolower')->call("hEllo World")
```